# databasedotcom gem sobject issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I am using the `databasedotcom` gem in a `Ruby on rails` app to access my Salesforce instance but I am having some trouble getting an `sObject` to be created under the correct namespace. I already have a model called `User` in my database, so when I first tried to get a list of `User` objects from Salesforce I was getting my locally defined model.

After reading around I found that I can specify a namespace for the client which I use to connect to my Salesforce instance, using `sobject_module`. I did that and I also defined a module in my project for the Salesforce models. However I still get back the locally defined `User` model rather than the Salesforce defined `User` model. If I try to access a model that is present in Salesforce but not locally then the object is returned under the correct namespace.

Why does this happen? I thought once I set the `sobject_module` for the client it should return the model under the correct namespace. Here is my client connection:

```
client = Databasedotcom::Client.new(
                client_id: "my_client_id",
                client_secret: "my_client_secret",
                sobject_module: "Sale"
            )

client.oauth_token = client.authenticate( username: "my_username", password: "my_password")
```

Here is the module i defined for the Salesforce objects:

```
module Sale

end
```

This works,  it returns `<Sale::Organization:0x007f90ef8ad590>`

```
client.materialize("Organization")
```

However this does not, it returns `<User:0x007f8f7e5a06d0>`

```
client.materialize("User")
```

Thanks in advance

***Update***

I was not able to get this to work for me, but I found another gem and it worked perfectly with it. I used the `restforce` gem

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already come to this conclusion, but Heroku is no longer maintaining the databasedotcom gem.